# Python - Saving a File being edited in GNU Nano 2.2.4

Tags: python, nano

I'm very new to programming and playing around with a Raspberry Pi and following tutorials on Youtube.

I have opened a file in GNU Nano 2.2.6 e.g: `nano my_File.py` and changed some of the data.

I'm struggling on how to overwrite the file (or save it) because when i run it in a new window it uses the original data...

Thanks.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you press `Ctrl-X`, for exit, it will ask you whether you want to save the file.
`Ctrl-O` is for saving file without exiting the editor.

`Ctrl-G` is for help on key combinations.

Comment: Thank you :) Perfect answer. I wasn't aware what the `^` represented. Problem solved. Thanks again.

Comment: Ow, and `M-<key>` in helpfile will refer to `Meta` key, in generic case - `Alt`