# How to exit apache config in Centos

Tags: linux, centos

I'm sure this is a really dumb question but I was installing LAMP and added index.php to my file and now I want to save and exit and I have no idea how to save and get off this screen. I'm sure it cant be that hard I cant work it out, this is my first time using centos-

http://puu.sh/5SK3E.png

Comment: Here is the same question (of using NANO editor):
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057924/python-saving-a-file-being-editted-in-gnu-nano-2-2-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Saving a File being edited in GNU Nano 2.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057924/python-saving-a-file-being-edited-in-gnu-nano-2-2-4)